# Recording logins for password protected directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

I have a folder in the webroot at `http://somesite.com/folder` which I'm password protecting with the directory password protection feature in cpanel which I guess uses some form of `htacccess`. So it's not protected with a normal login system that's connected to a database that I can check against.

Once a correct username and password is entered, a user can see the content of the folder

`http://somesite.com/folder/index.php`

I'm trying to find a php way to see what account was used to log into the folder. Anyone can think of a way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic, authentication, you'll have `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

For digest, you can [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']` or just look at `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` if you want the username (the password won't be available).

Comment: Thanks Artefacto, how do I know if it uses `basic` or `digest`? Do I just try it out and see which works, or something more to it?