# How about failed attempts for htaccess password protected directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication

This question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177122/recording-logins-for-password-protected-directories) I asked, but it's a different.

I'm using htaccess to control login to `http://somesite.com/folder`.

Once logged in, I have php code in `folder/index.php` to check the username and password used to login: `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. I log that info to a database.

This works when the user supplies a good username and password, but when it's incorrect, nothing happens - I suppose because `/index.php` is never reached.

Is there a way to login also failed login attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### EDIT

There's a simple way to do it. In your .htaccess, add

```
ErrorDocument 401 /path/to/log.php
```

This `log.php` is then called when a login attempt fails (you can put it behind the protected directory as well, it will be reached even though the login fails). Note that the browser doesn't know whether some resource needs authentication, so you'll always get a hit for the first attempt. These attempts, however, will not include any username and you can detect them (well, you can distinguish them from when the user enters no username, but you get the idea) by checking whether `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is empty.

#### Original

Well, no, as you say `/index.php` is never reached.

What you can do is not to rely on Apache at all and handle the authentication only with PHP. This [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) shows you how. This has a big disadvantage. Let's say you protected an entire directory. This directory has PHP files, images and whatnot. Now, to enforce the authentication, you must route everything through a PHP file. If you had only PHP files, you could do it with an include. If you have static contented, you must route it with a rewrite-rule through a PHP files that reads and outputs the static content, which will hurt the performance.

Comment: I have an idea, what if I still protected `/folder/` with htaccess, but did the logging in an external file. I would direct the user to `check.php` outside the protected folder. The only job of that file is to record all attempts (good or bad, in fact `check.php` doesn't know if it's good or bad since it just logs it to the database), then passes the input programmatically to the login box that runs with htaccess. I guess for this to work, I would have to somehow feed the entered username and password to the htaccess login box programmatically, is that possible?

Comment: @dev I don't think it would much easier. It would probably be best to use `mod_authn_dbd` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) and record attempts with database triggers.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to lock out users who repeatedly fail authentication, you could keep using Apache basic auth and just install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).  Set it and forget it!