# 500 error when setting up directory protection with mod_authn_dbd

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, authentication

I'm trying to use `mod_authn_dbd` to password protect a directory.

I used the code from their [apache help page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html), but it's chocking on the `DBDriver` line

```
# mod_dbd configuration
DBDriver mysql //modified
DBDParams "dbname=mydbname user=myuser password=mypass" //modified
```

`/path/to/folder/.htaccess: Invalid command 'DBDriver', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

The documentation says `Please note that you need to load an authorization module, such as mod_authz_user, to get it working.` but I have no idea how to do that.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: +1 to previous. Single error message worth 1000 lines of code.

Comment: usually you do. as for the particular location, it's a question should be addressed to the hosting support, not strangers from another site. But usually it can be found in the root folder of your account or virtual host. Just check it all using your ftp client

Comment: If you're on shared hosting, it's possible the mysql driver is not compiled in or the mod_authn_dbd module is not loaded.

Comment: I found `Errors Log` in cPanel and it has an interesting line `/path/to/folder/.htaccess: Invalid command 'DBDriver', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` so Artefacto's comment re `the mod_authn_dbd module is not loaded` may be it?

Comment: The documentation says `Please note that you need to load an authorization module, such as mod_authz_user, to get it working.` but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @dev I updated my response here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177280) to include an alternative approach to login failed attempts.